# Completely disable scrolling of webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to disable scrolling for my webpage, but completely, not just disable scrollbars so

```
overflow: hidden
```

will not work.

Also this workaround does not apply on Macs due to the "soft-scroll" on edges. It will show a terrible shaky animation:

```
window.onscroll = function () {
window.scrollTo(0,0);
}
```

Is there any other method to disable scrolling completely?

Comment: Can you show why `overflow: hidden` isn't working for you?  Provide some example code.

Comment: overflow: hidden just removes the scrollbar but it won't disable scrolling with the scroll wheel (I'm talking about vertical scrolling)

Comment: overflow: hidden usually works perfect for me. I think you should provide some example like @Brad said.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10144170/362536

Comment: Then you need to specify a height.

Comment: Why are you trying this - the browser is their property and therefore it is up to them to scroll.

Comment: With overflow hidden you can still click & drag to see the rest of the content. Scrolling doesn't work though (for me).

Comment: Example: http://jsfiddle.net/67xQZ/ I can't get it to scroll on my Mac, not with a scroll wheel or with the touchpad. I think you need to show a complete example that shows your problem.

Comment: Maybe this throws some light: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656592/how-to-programmatically-disable-page-scrolling-with-jquery

Comment: @KarimGeiger I know exactly what you are talking about. but I am not sure how to fix it. I would suggest looking at some examples on other sites and looking at the source code maybe that can shed some light.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Presuming the simplified HTML code is:

```
<html><body><div class=wrap>content...</div></body></html>
```

Set both body, html to height:100%;

```
body, html {height:100%;}
```

Put a div inside body, and set it to stretch across all the body height:

```
div.wrap {height:100%; overflow:hidden;}
```

This will prevent window from scrolling in weird ways, like, pressing mouse wheel and moving it, using anchors, etc.

To remove the scroll bar itself (visually), you should also add:

```
body {overflow: hidden; }
```

---

To disable scrolling via pressing arrow keys on keyboard:

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    // space, page up, page down and arrow keys:
    if([32, 33, 34, 37, 38, 39, 40].indexOf(e.keyCode) > -1) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: Chances are, if I'm disabling scrolling, I want to use the whole window. This can be done with `body{margin:0}`. Otherwise (at least on my Chrome set-up) you lose a small border.

Comment: FWIW, I disagree that this topic is a duplicate. The topic pointed to is more about text which overflows to the right, so it's useful for `<verbatim>`. This topic is about the whole view area, so it's useful for `<canvas>`. Obviously there's a large overlap, but a consequence is that Sych's answer has a low rating there and a high rating here.

Comment: when the page is bigger and has scroll, and you are in bottom, when disable scroll, it goes to the top of the web, how can u avoid that auto scroll 0 ?